# Deploying a Padrino app using capistrano (bundler: failed to load command: padrino)

Tags: ruby, capistrano, padrino

I'm trying to deploy my Padrino application using Capistrano, but  when I run the command: `cap deploy` the following output is generated:

```
//... Other tasks executed properly      
  * 2016-11-05 16:23:26 executing `assets:prepare'
  * executing "cd /data/apps/myapp/current; RACK_ENV=production bundle exec padrino rake assets:prepare"
    servers: ["my_server_DNS_name"]
    [my_server_DNS_name] executing command
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] => Executing Rake assets:prepare ...
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] RSpec is not part of this bundle, skip specs.
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] W, [2016-11-05T20:23:28.664995 #14317]  WARN -- : Error creating log directory log/, using standard out for logging.
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "production" environment.
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Enabling the Request Sampler.
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Environment: production
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : No known dispatcher detected.
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Application: myapp (Production)
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] WARN : Audit log disabled, failed opening log at '/data/apps/myapp/releases/20161105202309/log/newrelic_audit.log': File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /data/apps/myapp/releases/20161105202309/log
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack instrumentation
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:28 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:29 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/626868/applications/2669966
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] bundler: failed to load command: padrino (/data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/padrino)
 ** [out :: my_server_DNS_name] [11/05/16 20:23:29 +0000 ip-172-31-16-177 (14317)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] Errno::EEXIST: File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /data/apps/myapp/releases/20161105202309/log
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `fu_mkdir'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `reverse_each'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `block in mkdir_p'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `each'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `mkdir_p'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/padrino-core-0.12.0/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:283:in `setup!'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/padrino-core-0.12.0/lib/padrino-core/loader.rb:56:in `load!'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/releases/20161105202309/config/boot.rb:52:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/padrino-core-0.12.0/lib/padrino-core/cli/rake_tasks.rb:12:in `require'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/padrino-core-0.12.0/lib/padrino-core/cli/rake_tasks.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/padrino-core-0.12.0/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:62:in `rake'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/padrino-core-0.12.0/bin/padrino:9:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/padrino:23:in `load'
*** [err :: my_server_DNS_name] /data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/padrino:23:in `<top (required)>'
    command finished in 3322ms
failed: "env RACK_ENV=production rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm /home/deploy/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '2.1' -c 'cd /data/apps/myapp/current; RACK_ENV=production bundle exec padrino rake assets:prepare'" on my_server_DNS_name
```

The main thing I don't understand is why the padrino command couldn't be loaded because I am able to see the file in the path: `/data/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/padrino`. How can I debug this problem?

Could it be related with the `WARN -- : Error creating log directory log/, using standard out for logging.` problem (I don't think it could be related but...)

I've spent some time googling but without luck.